# Does taquito have a way to parse the parameters of the entry-point in an operation?

Tags: taquito

Does taquito have a way to parse the parameters of the entry-point in an operation? For Example:

```
"parameters":{
  "entrypoint":"do_transfer",
  "value":[
    {
      "prim":"Pair",
      "args":[
        {
          "bytes":"0000d0bf37609c311a6583a098ce2dbd590732d464b1"
        },
        [
          {
            "prim":"Pair",
            "args":[
              {
                "bytes":"000096bb5d1bcc69811fed7b1aabba544418a673a3e9"
              },
              {
                "prim":"Pair",
                "args":[
                  {
                    "int":"0"
                  },
                  {
                    "int":"200"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [@taquito/michelson-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@taquito/michelson-encoder)

> The Michelson-Encoder package aims to create an abstraction over the Michelson Language. It allows converting Michelson data into javascript-looking objects which are easier to use and reason about.
> Its integration into the main Taquito package makes it easier to write the storage when deploying a contract and the parameter when calling a contract entry-point or executing a view. It also provides an abstraction on the storage read value of the contract.
> The Schema class is intended to represent the contract storage, while the ParameterSchema represents its entry points. **The Execute method takes a parameter in Michelson format and converts it into the JavaScript abstraction.** The Encode method does the opposite; it takes a JavaScript object as a parameter and converts it into Michelson data.

```
const data = storageSchema.Execute(dataMichelson);
console.log(data);

/* output:
{
  "stored_counter": "10",
  "threshold": "5",
  "keys": [
    "edpkvS5QFv7KRGfa3b87gg9DBpxSm3NpSwnjhUjNBQrRUUR66F7C9g",
    "edpkuLxx9PQD8fZ45eUzrK3BhfDZJHhBuK4Zi49DcEGANwd2rpX82t"
  ]
} 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`.toTransferParams()` can be helpful in this case.

Something like

```
      const contract = await Tezos.contract.at('KT1...')
      const inspect =  contract.methods.default([...]).toTransferParams()
      console.log(inspect.parameter)
```

Here's a link to live code example on the website. https://tezostaquito.io/docs/complex_parameters/#inspect-parameter

If it's not what you're looking for feel free to give us more context to help you further.